Integrating with respect to conditional probability measure (while conditioning on measure zero set)
Let $X, Y$ be (possibly dependent) random variables taking values in $\mathbb{R}^m, \mathbb{R}^n$ respectively with distributions $\mu_X, \mu_Y$ respectively. We do not assume that $X,Y$ have densities. We define (as I believe is standard, in order to handle conditioning on measure zero sets) for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, the measure $\mu_{Y \vert X = x}$ on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as
$$
\mu_{Y \vert X = x}(B) = \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{I}_{Y \in B} \vert X = x] \equiv P(Y \in B \vert X = x).
$$
Assume for any Borel set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ that we are given an expression for the conditional probability $P(Y \in B \vert X = x)$.
Under these assumptions, I want to show the following two things.
Q1. Show for Borel sets $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ that
$$
P(X \in A \cap Y \in B) = \int_{A} P(Y \in B \vert X = x) d\mu_X(x).
$$
Q2. Show that for any Borel measurable function $q: \mathbb{R}^{m + n} \to \mathbb{R}$, whose expectation $\mathbb{E}[q(X, Y)]$ is finite, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[q(X, Y)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} q(x, y) \; d\mu_{Y \vert X = x}(y) d\mu_X(x).
$$
I was able to successfully show Q1, which follows from basic properties of the conditional expectation.
Regarding Q2, I tried the standard approach of "complicating" $q$. In particular, I started by showing the statement true for $q$ being an indicator function, then $q$ being a simple function, and then approximating a generic non-negative $q$ with simple functions and the Monotone Convergence Theorem, and finally handling a generic $q$ by splitting it into its positive and negative portions.
Unfortunately, I think there is a bug in my attempt at showing Q2 in the case when $q$ is an indicator function. Concretely, I assumed $q(z) = \mathbb{I}_{z \in C}$ for Borel $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$, and then said this implies that
$$q(X, Y) = \mathbb{I}_{X \in A \cap Y \in B},$$
for $A, B$ as Borel in $\mathbb{R}^m, \mathbb{R}^n$ respectively. If this implication was true, then we are fine, since I can use the result of Q1 to show the desired result. But I think this implication is false.
In particular, it is not true that for a Borel set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$, that we have $C_m, C_n$ as Borel in $\mathbb{R}^m, \mathbb{R}^n$ respectively (where $C_m, C_n$ are the first $m$ and latter $n$ coordinates of $C$ respectively). And my argument was basically hinging on defining $A = C_m$ and $B = C_n$, but this would mean that $A,B$ are not necessarily Borel and so everything breaks.
So now I am not sure how to prove Q2. Is Q2 even true (it seems very intuitive)? If it is not true, then surely there is some similar statement under some additional mild condition which is true?
I appreciate the help in advance.

More general. Let $\Omega_1(\Gamma_1)\times\Omega_2(\Gamma_2)$ be a product of measurable spaces on which a probability $P_{\Omega_1\circ\Omega_2}$ is defined, and let $P_{\Omega_1}, P_{\Omega_2}$ be the respective marginal probabilities. A (regular) conditional probability of $\Omega_1$ over $\Omega_2$ is a function $P_{\Omega_1/\Omega_2}:\Omega_2\rightarrow \textbf{P}_{\Omega_1}$ that associates to each $\omega_2\in\Omega_2$ a probability $P_{\Omega_1/\Omega_2}(\omega_2)$ in $\Omega_1$, such that, for every $P_{\Omega_1\circ\Omega_2}$-integrable function $f:\Omega_1\times\Omega_2\rightarrow \textbf{R}$, it is:
$$\int f(\omega_1,\omega_2)dP_{\Omega_1\circ\Omega_2}=\int dP_{\Omega_2}.\int f(\omega_1,\omega_2)dP_{\Omega_1/\Omega_2}(\omega_2)$$
For which, by continuity of the integral, it is sufficient that, for all $A\in\Gamma_1, B\in\Gamma_2$:
$$\int_{A\times B} dP_{\Omega_1\circ\Omega_2}=\int_B dP_{\Omega_2}.\int_A dP_{\Omega_1/\Omega_2}(\omega_2)$$
In your case, if $X,Y$ are variables defined in $\Omega$, $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ would be $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ respectively with $P_{\Omega_1\circ\Omega_2}(A\times B)=P_\Omega(X\in A\cap Y\in B)=P_\Omega((X\times Y)\in (A\times B))$. And it would be:
$$ E[f(X,Y)]=\int f(x,y)dP_{X\circ Y}=\int dP_Y.\int f(x,y)dP_{X/Y}(y)$$
and
$$P_{X\circ Y}(A\times B)=P_\Omega (X\in A\cap Y\in B)=\int_{A\times B}dP_{X\circ Y}=\int_B dP_Y.\int_A dP_{X/Y}(y)$$

Thank you for the help. Shouldn't it be $\int f(x, y) dP_{X \cdot Y} = \int \int f(x,y) dP_{X/Y}(y) dP_Y$? In the sense that the inner integral is over the variable $x$ while holding $y$ fixed. This leaves a function of $y$, and then the outer integral is over $y$?
By contrast, you wrote $\int f(x, y) dP_{X \cdot Y} = \int dP_Y \cdot \int f(x,y) dP_{X/Y}(y)$, which I am not sure how to interpret, since it seems to be the product of a real number with a function of $y$?

It should be and is what you say. It would make no sense to interpret it any other way.

thanks. i accepted the answer but have just one more question. it seems that we need a rigorous notion a regular conditional probability, because just setting the conditional probability of $A$ to be the conditional expectation of $A$ can lead to some issues regarding null sets. Can you please explain this? i guess it has something to do with the fact that the conditional expectation is unique only upto nulls sets? i appreciate your help!
